# Stored procedure to return a bool

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure that checks if the email the user is saving (edit profile email) to check if the new email already exists in the database for a different user or not. If the email entered doesn't exist in database then safe to use and save but if it exists in database and the user id and name don't match the user id and name of the person saving meaning the new email belongs to a different user return false which i will use to throw and error message

here is what i have:

```
create procedure CheckDuplicate
@email nvarchar(256),
@Id int
As
Begin
set nocount on;
select usr.Id, usr.UserName, usr.Email
from Users usr
where usr.Email = @email and usr.Id = @Id
end
```

**Question:**  how can i add bool to check if it exists or not in the database?

Comment: I believe the question is: Does this `@email` address belong to anyone other than this user `@Id`? If it is unassigned, or belongs to the user in question, then it can be updated. If it already belongs to another user then there is a problem. The current answers do not all implement this logic.

Comment: @HABO yes your understanding of the question is right - i want to check the email the user is updating exists in db to another user or not - if so return true(that is already taken) else false(not taken and can be used)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
create procedure CheckDuplicate
@email nvarchar(256),
@Id int
As
Begin

set nocount on;

   Select Case When Exists (
      select usr.Id, usr.UserName, usr.Email
      from Users usr
      where usr.Email = @email and usr.Id = @Id
   )
   Then Cast(1 as bit)
   Else Cast(0 as bit) 
   End


End
```

Comment: with this will i be able to use it in my web app (c# asp.net mvc) to check if false then i could use it and if true i can't?

Comment: Yes, the returned value from the stored procedure will be a boolean, you'll need read this value when the stored procedure result is returned. This is the same concept as selecting a boolean (bit in SQL) column and returning it as part of the result set.

Answer (score 2):

This will return 1 if another user has the requested email address, otherwise 0:

```
create procedure CheckDuplicate
  @email nvarchar(256),
  @Id int
As
  set nocount on;
  select case
    when exists ( select 42 from Users where Email = @email and Id <> @Id ) then Cast( 1 as Bit )
    else Cast( 0 as Bit ) end as EmailBelongsToAnotherUser
```

Alternatively, you could return the result in an output parameter:

```
create procedure CheckDuplicate
  @email nvarchar(256),
  @Id int,
  @EmailCollision as Bit Output
As
  set nocount on;
  select @EmailCollision = case
    when exists ( select 42 from Users where Email = @email and Id <> @Id ) then Cast( 1 as Bit )
    else Cast( 0 as Bit ) end as EmailBelongsToAnotherUser
```

This is somewhat more efficient as there is no need to create a recordset to pass a single bit.

Note that this should really be done in the same transaction that updates the database. Otherwise someone else might sneak in and you'll have a conflict.

Comment: When i return false for that the email is already taken and considered a duplicate i get false (which is the right result) but i also see ResultValue = 0. Shouldn't the ResultValue = 1 (for the existing email address)?

Comment: The result that I calculate, `EmailBelongsToAnotherUser`, is the opposite of what you expect. How are you getting `ResultValue`? You can use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.100).aspx) to get the result of the first stored procedure. Are you sure you're not getting the exit status of the procedure? That is always 0 if there were no errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
--IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')

create procedure CheckDuplicate
@email nvarchar(256),
@Id int
As
Begin
set nocount on;
IF EXISTS (select usr.Id, usr.UserName, usr.Email
from Users usr
where usr.Email = @email and usr.Id = @Id)
begin
Print 'YES' 
end
else
begin
Print 'NO' 
end

end
```

Comment: not getting the yes or no to print just returns 0 or the actual userinfo depending on what i passed in

Comment: return 1 for yes and 0 for No.. you can modified the code for your need. Print with print syntax in the logfile or in SSMS.